# Format output of Bash Script on webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, render

I am running a bash script from a nodejs server and then sending the output of that over to a webpage where it is being displayed. I want to be able to style the output and not have it appear as just a bunch of text. Right now the script outputs this:

```
Disk quotas for user {USER} : 
 Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
hpcstore03:/hpc_home/home
              33528   5120M   5120M            2668   4295m   4295m
```

This is run asynchronously on the server and then a render function is called that displays a webpage and all the page has on it is the output of the script. So something like:

```
  router.get("/", function(request, response){
    exec('/usr/local/bin/foobar', function(error, stdout, stderr){
      response.render('index', {
        baseUri: baseUri,
        output: stdout,
        title: "foobar",
        error: stderr,
      });
    });
  });
```

And the webpage code is just:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<pre>{{output}}</pre>
```

So how do I get the output to be formatted, like if I wanted to bold parts of it, or put separate parts of the output into a table? Would I write some javascript to be ran locally that would search through the {{output}} string and load parts of it into elements on the page? I'm not quite sure if that would work anyways because I am new to the whole rendering using {{}} syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to generate an HTML from `stdout`. You could split it by newlines and therefore having four lines. Wrap a `<p></p>` around those. But before you do that, split the elements by the whitespace separator you have, put the individual words into `<span></span>` and make sure you style the `font-weight` for some keywords, like **FileSystem** and make sure the `span`s have a proper `padding-righ`t, so they will have spaces between them. Naturally, you can do a lot more, these are just some basic suggestions.

Comment: What do you mean by generate an HTML from stdout? How would I do that? and then split it by newlines?

Comment: @ZachMunro stdout is a parameter, so it must have a string value. And if you have a string foo, you can split it by newline and put this into a paragraph like this: '<p>' + foo.split("\n").join('</p><p>'); + '</p>'. Try this out with stdout and if you load the page and view the page source of the browser and see the <p> tags there, then you are on the right track towards a solution.